# sortIdx does not work with C++

Tags: python, sorting, opencv

I am trying to sort elements of 1D openCV Mat in descending order. My python code seems to work fine using sortIdx function of openCV. But code is not working in C++, where my index list contains zero values.

**C++ code**

```
cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat(5, 1,CV_32F);
temp.setTo(10);
temp.at<float>(2, 0) = 20;
temp.at<float>(4, 0) = 40;
cv::Mat ind;
cv::sortIdx(temp, ind, CV_SORT_DESCENDING);
```

**Python Code**

```
kernel = np.ones((7,1), np.int32)  
kernel[5]=10    
p =cv2.sortIdx(kernel, cv2.SORT_DESCENDING+cv2.SORT_EVERY_COLUMN)
```

My output index array turns out to be zero with C++ code which is strange ... I tried a lot but don't know what's going on with C++ code

Answer (score 0):

For C++ version, according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20sortIdx(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flags)),

> The function sortIdx sorts each matrix row or each matrix column in the ascending or descending order. So you should pass two operation flags to get desired behaviour.

So the correct way is

```
cv::sortIdx(temp, ind, CV_SORT_EVERY_COLUMN + CV_SORT_DESCENDING);
```

Comment: I have tried that as well but nothing returns in the matrix ... it seems to be empty when I print out ind

Comment: @user1388142 That is strange... It works well in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

**It's working now**

Normally, sortIdx returns MAT of type ushort. I was trying to create a MAT of type float and display it, which was not working. Now everything works perfectly fine

```
Mat t = cvCreateMat(3,6,CV_32F);
t.setTo(1);
t.at<float>(0,0)=10;
t.at<float>(1,1)=20;
t.at<float>(2,1)=30;
t.at<float>(1,2)=5;
t.at<float>(2,4)=16;
t.at<float>(0,5)=40;
t.at<float>(0,2)=140;
cout<<t<<"\n";

Mat t1= cvCreateMat(t.rows* t.cols, 1, CV_32F);
t1 = t.reshape(1,t.rows*t.cols);


Mat ind= cvCreateMat(t.rows*t.cols,1,CV_16U);
sortIdx(t1, ind,  CV_SORT_EVERY_COLUMN | CV_SORT_DESCENDING);

for(int i=0;i<ind.rows;i++)
{
    cout<<ind.at<ushort>(i,0)<<"\t\t"<<t1.at<float>(i,0)<<"\n";
}

for(int i=0;i<ind.rows;i++)
{
    int row = ind.at<ushort>(i,0);
    int col = ind.at<ushort>(i,0);
    row = row /t.cols;
    col = col% t.cols;

    cout<<row<<"\t"<<col<<"\n";
}
getchar();
return 0;
```